# rails model complex association explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I am new to rails. I found out this code in one of rails sample
 project.

```
has_many :all_ticket_fields, -> { 
where(parent_id: nil)
.includes([:picklist_values, :flexifield_def_entry]) 
.order(:position)
}, class_name: 'DVClass::NormalSection'
```

Can you please explain this?

Comment: please don't downvote. I have found this section of code in the office sample project where I am supposed to work upon.

Comment: Which model is it in?

Comment: active record model

Comment: name of the model?

Comment: app/models/account/itil_associations.rb

Comment: Models are supposed to be singular. It should be `itil_association.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one-to-many assoictaion between `ItilAssociation` and `DVClass::NormalSection`, suppose you fetched a record from `ItilAssociation`

```
itil = ItilAssociation.first
```

`itil.all_ticket_fields` will basically run this query,

```
DVClass::NormalSelection.where(itil_association_id: itil.id)
                        .where(parent_id: nil)
                        .includes([:picklist_values, :flexifield_def_entry]) 
                        .order(:position)
```

`has_many` with conditions is just a way to return associated records based on conditions.

Hope that helped!

Comment: @PushpendraSingh np, just upvoted your question as it was to the point.